# Convert string structure in another

Tags: python, string, shell

I have a file with this pattern :

```
[account.invoice.set_num]
job_size = 0
trans_size = 100

[commission.invoice_second.create_full]
j_size = 0

[commission.invoice_principal.finalize]
j_size = 12
in_directory = /to/the/directory
```

I want to transform this pattern to a text like :

```
ACCOUNT_INVOICE_SET_NUM_JOB_SIZE = 0
ACCOUNT_INVOICE_SET_NUM_TRANS_SIZE = 100
COMMISSION_INVOICE_SECOND_CREATE_FULL_J_SIZE=0
COMMISSION_INVOICE_PRINCIPALE_FINALIZE_J_SIZE=12 
COMMISSION_INVOICE_PRINCIPALE_FINALIZE_IN_DIRECTORY=/to/the/directory
```

I try to do that in Bash unix or in Python.
I don't konw what is the best/easiest way to do that.

Comment: post your starting code

Comment: For example, in python i could use https://docs.python.org/3/library/configparser.html

Comment: Probably the tool you have more experience with.

Comment: you "could use" - show those attempts

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's quite feasible with [config.ConfigParser](https://docs.python.org/3/library/configparser.html#configparser-objects) features:

```
from configparser import ConfigParser

config = ConfigParser()
config.read('yourfile')

config_lines = ''
for section in config.sections():
    s_key = section.replace('.', '_')   # transformed section key
    for k, v in config.items(section):
        config_lines += f'{s_key}_{k}'.upper() + f'={v}\n'

print(config_lines)
```

The output:

```
ACCOUNT_INVOICE_SET_NUM_JOB_SIZE=0
ACCOUNT_INVOICE_SET_NUM_TRANS_SIZE=100
COMMISSION_INVOICE_SECOND_CREATE_FULL_J_SIZE=0
COMMISSION_INVOICE_PRINCIPAL_FINALIZE_J_SIZE=12
COMMISSION_INVOICE_PRINCIPAL_FINALIZE_IN_DIRECTORY=/to/the/directory
```

Comment: Thank you @romanPerkhrest. I think python and this library is the best choice.